# Can I extends contentProvider without my own database?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Can I create a class extends ContentProvider without my own database? Instead, I return the cursor from other ContentProvider. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

well, from the code, may be you can do that.

but i dont think it's a good idea, you can return the cursor from `another content provider`, why not directed to use the `another content provider`.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do that. However, you have to properly implement the ContentProvider. How you do that and where the `Cursor` comes from is quite irrelevant. Obviously I partially agree with @idiottiger where it might be simpler just to directly use the existing content provider.